# text spliting of column based on comma in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split the text column (hashtag). I have used the split function but creating another column doesnt help.

```
ID     date        hashtag
123  1/1/1990     #cause,#contain
345  1/3/1990     #abc, #ghy,#hhh,#
```

output:

```
ID     date        hashtag
123  1/1/1990     #cause
123  1/1/1990     #contain
345  1/3/1990     #abc
345  1/3/1990     #ghy
345  1/3/1990    #hhh
345  1/3/1990     #
```

Comment: Is this about a Pandas dataframe? If so, use the Pandas tag.

Comment: I assumed this is pandas based on your previous question, but please make it explicit as @AKX requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is `pandas` (based on your previous questions), you can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the hashtag with a regex (`,\s*` = comma with optional spaces) and then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the column:

```
(df.assign(hashtag=df['hashtag'].str.split(',\s*'))
   .explode('hashtag')
)
```

output:

```
    ID      date   hashtag
0  123  1/1/1990    #cause
0  123  1/1/1990  #contain
1  345  1/3/1990      #abc
1  345  1/3/1990      #ghy
1  345  1/3/1990      #hhh
1  345  1/3/1990         #
```

Comment: great it works. One doubt is why it created an additional column of values as NA

Comment: Probably you already had a NaN column before. This code should not create new columns.